# Ember CLI generate component in an addon

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I try to make an addon using ember-cli. Here it is step by step what I have done so far:

```
sudo ember addon test-addon
cd test-addon
sudo ember serve
```

now the server runs and on localhost:4200 I can see the test/dummy app's application hbs.

> **Welcome to Ember.js**

Its time to make some components for the addon:

```
sudo ember g component my-form
```

In the **tests/dummy/app/templates/application.hbs** I added 
**{{my-form}}**

And now I'm getting the following js error:

*Uncaught Error: Could not find module `test-addon/components/my-form` imported from `dummy/components/my-form`*

### edit

After struggling a little bit with npm, I tried it again (without sudo) and the same thing happened. I'm on Ember CLI 0.2.1. Here are my files, but they should be the same since they are auto-generated. The error is thrown from **bower-components/loader.js/loader.js line 110**.

**addon/components/my-form.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import layout from '../templates/components/my-form';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  layout: layout
});
```

**addon/templates/components/my-form.hbs**

```
{{yield}}
```

**app/components/my-form.js**

```
import myForm from 'test-addon/components/my-form';

export default myForm;
```

Comment: You shouldn't be sudo-ing those commands.

Comment: I know, but if i don't do it, then i am getting permission failures.

Comment: Tried it. Not experiencing this issue with ember-cli 0.2.1

Comment: Go to your ~/.npm folder and change ownership from `root` to your username and group. Then try ember commands without sudo.

Comment: @user3568719 were u able to fix it?

Comment: @blessenm yes, but TBH I don't remember what was the issue. A simple reboot helped. I also recommend you to install Ember CLI *without* sudo. It avoids a lot of problems.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like ([as of July 2015, anyway](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-cli-addon-with-template/7230/5)) that the fact templates don't work in addons is partially by design.  Philosophically, I guess the justification is that the styling should be app-specific, but the JS logic can be shared.  Or it's just a bug/oversight.

It turns out that if you simply remove that layout line and the import layout, it will work.

So the result looks like:

`<app-name>/app/templates/includes-a-shared-component.hbs`:

```
What follows is my shared component! {{my-shared-component}}
```

`<addon-name>/addon/components/my-shared-component.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  valueFromProperty:function() { // simple hello-world-style function
    return 5;
  }.property()
});
```

`<app-name>/app/templates/components/my-shared-component.hbs`:

```
Hey look I'm the app-specific style for your component <marquee>Hello world</marquee>
Here's a value from a property: {{valueFromProperty}}
```

My versions:
Ember: 1.13.1
node: 0.12.0
npm: 2.12.1

Answer (score 0):

And here's a very different (and IMO better, but not perfect) answer than my earlier one.

`<addon-name>addon/components/test-component.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  valueFromProperty:function() {
    return 5;
  }.property(),

  layout:Ember.HTMLBars.compile("I'm the addon's layout {{valueFromProperty}}")
});
```

You will need to add the template compiler to your app:

`<app-name>/app/ember-cli-build.js`:

```
/* global require, module */
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // Add options here
  });
  app.import('bower_components/ember/ember-template-compiler.js');
  ... other stuff...
```

Note that the layout property in the addon's component completely overrides your in-app template, so per-app customizing becomes more difficult.  But if you want your template customizable, you could probably use my other answer where you don't specify layout at all and just let the resolver find the template in your app.

Comment: Your first answer is the convention, I'm not sure what the benefit of this version would be. You're not supposed to ship the template compiler to production and it would be rather rude of an addon to do so, and inlining the handlebars in the component breaks separation of concerns. See for instance: https://github.com/miguelcobain/ember-paper

Comment: I'm imagining some primarily-UI component whose layout doesn't have to change from app to app.  It'd be fairly annoying to install an addon but then have to build your own .hbs (or manually add the recommended .hbs).

Perhaps I'm in the wrong, but I'm imagining this addon like a self-contained library, and if someone wants to use a component from it, they just slap it down without worrying about further styling/configuration.  Ideally it'd just have the template in addon/templates/components/my-component.hbs, but that seems banned.

Comment: You don't have to add anything, ember-cli takes care of it.

Comment: Ah, got it.  It was not clear to me that `<addon>/addon/components` was a different scope than `<addon>/app/components`.  In fact, in my answers, I meant app/templates or addon/templates as really meaning `<app-name>/app/templates` and `<addon-name>/addon/templates`.

Answer (score 0):

One more approach I've found that works and is different than my other answers.

Let's say you've done `ember g component my-addon-component` in your addon.

This will result in you having a component at: `<addon-name>/addon/components/my-addon-component.js` and a template at `<addon-name>/addon/templates/my-addon-component.hbs` (at least with my current ember-cli).
You'll also have a tiny component stub at `<addon-name>/app/components/my-addon-component.js`

The fix:
 1. Move the component guts from `<addon-name>/addon/components` to `<addon-name>/app/components` (replacing the stub).
 2. Move the template from `<addon-name>/addon/templates/components` to `<addon-name/app/templates/components`

After 1: The `import layout from ../templates/components/my-addon-component` will now have a different meaning: it'll be importing from the including-app's namespace instead of the addon's namespace.

After 2: The template's import location will be in the including-app's namespace.  This also seems to mean it gets compiled by the app, so you won't throw the "addon templates were detected, but there are no template compilers registered"